# How do perform proper backups in Apache Sling

Tags: backup, sling, jcr, jackrabbit

I am planning the backup strategy for my sling application. In my application users are able to register themselves and create their own content. 
To be able to recover from a crash I tried to create a content package by using the composum package manager. This kind of backup works fine for the content but not for the users.

Any ideas how to backup my user-created users?

BR
Tim

Answer (score 1):

From the Question, I comprehend that you have a JCR Repository as your content Repository and you have an apache sling middle ware which talks to JCR Repository.
Since Apache sling is a middleware which does not have any storage or users on its own I believe you are mentioning about Users in JCR.

Then you may try to follow this article in order to export or backup any data in XML. Content in JCR repository can be exported to xml.

https://jackrabbit.apache.org/archive/wiki/JCR/BackupAndMigration_115513344.html

Comment: Thank you I will try that :)